# Why is my "catalina.out" 500MB big?

Tags: logging, tomcat

I noticed that my `catalina.out` in `/var/log/tomcat` is this big... why? How do I avoid this?

Comment: Disable logging, maybe? Look what's in it – is it necessary?

Comment: Yes it is! Is there a way to have it cut the file like log4j does?

Comment: See: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/03/howto-rotate-tomcat-catalina-out/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Apache Tomcat [Logging FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging), which points to a [thread](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=105645816302666&w=2) on how to rotate catalina.out:

> On Unix I simply pipe the catalina.sh command to /usr/bin/cronolog and
>   it rotates the log for me. See www.cronolog.org for more info...

And as @slhck points out, there are some other [good instructions](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/03/howto-rotate-tomcat-catalina-out/) on catalina.out rotation.